nuxt 3 как убрать utils из autoImports
Всем привет, не могу разобраться, как не отключая автоимпорты убрать какую-либо зависимость. Например, мне нужны автоимпорты composables и стандартных функций, но stores и utils не нужны, как я могу это сделать? Заранее спасибо всем за ответы!

Если у кого-то такая же проблема, что и у меня, то этот вариант подойдет:


export default defineNuxtConfig({  
  hooks: {
    'imports:dirs'(dirs) {
      const rules = ['utils'];

      for (const rule of rules) {
        const index = dirs.findIndex((dir) => dir.includes(rule));

        dirs.splice(index, 1);
      }
    }
  },
})



